# How to dynamically change UserControl on TreeViewItem Selection in MVVM Light WPF C# (Without hard coding TreeView Selection event in View )

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, treeview

I am working with MVVM Light and I have a simple question. I want to dynamically change the UserControl  (Hosted by Content Control On the MainWindow) on TreeViewItem Selection.

---

### Work Done

I created a property in the MainViewModel that keep tracks of the current selected ViewModel.

```
private ViewModelBase currentviewmodel;
readonly static ViewModel1 VM1 = new ViewModel1();
readonly static ViewModel2 VM2 = new ViewModel2();

public ViewModelBase CurrentViewModel
{
   get
   {
      return currentviewmodel;
   }
   set
   {
      if (currentviewmodel != value)
      {
         currentviewmodel = value;
         RaisePropertyChanged("CurrentViewModel");
      }
   }
}
```

I Have also created a DataTemplate in the Windows.Resource of the respective ViewModel to change the UserControl on Selection

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel1}" >
            <Tu:View1/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModel2}" >
            <Tu:View2 />
        </DataTemplate>
```

Now the only concern is  how should i databind the CurrentViewModel property in the treeview so that the Usercontrol in the content control changes???

---

### EDIT

HDT in Windows.resource

```
 <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding list}" DataType="{x:Type th:Tu}">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Label Content="{Binding list}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

```
<TreeView Name="Tree" Background="#FF808080" Margin="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Tubelist}" />
```

The treeview is bound to a list of name.Those name corresponds to the UserControl,what i want is that on selection of that names in the treeview the respective usercontrol should be selected.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data bound `TreeView`, you can just bind `ContentControl.Content` to its `SelectedItem`:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=myTreeView}"/>
```

Thus, you even don't need `CurrentViewModel` property.

Comment: Thanks for ur Response!!!!   Can you please elaborate... srry i forgot to mention! I have a list  bound to itemsSource of treeview and on selection of that node the contentControl should should host the US-Ctrl.The list bounded to the Treeview is the list of the name of usercontrol to be displayed

Comment: "The list bounded to the Treeview is the list of the name of usercontrol to be displayed" - have you bound to the `TreeView.ItemsSource` list of strings?? If no, show treeview XAML, please, and view model's property, bound to `ItemsSource`

Comment: I have posted the code of the treeviewand yes TV`s Itemsource is bounded to a list of string.